# como leer el valor de una cookie en react para mantener una sesion de usuario?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Estoy tratando de implementar un login de usuario con react. Le estoy enviando una cookie creada con cookie-parser desde node para mantener la sesión del usuario, pero no logro acceder a ese valor con react, probe con la librería js-cookie pero no lee el valor de una cookie ya creada, me devuelve siempre un objeto vacío.
Alguna idea o sugerencia? Gracias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

export default function Login(props) {
const [data, setData] = useState({})
const [error,setError] = useState('')
const [login, setLogin] = useState(false)

const endpoint = "http://localhost:4000/users/login"

 axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

function handleChange(e) {
    const {name,value} = e.target;
    setData({

        ...data,
        [name] : value
    })

}

useEffect(() =>  {
  axios.get(endpoint).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      
  }) }, [login])


const read = Cookies.get()
console.log(read)

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post(endpoint,data).then(res => {
      
            console.log(res)
            setLogin(true)
          
            }).catch(Error => {
            setError("Hubo un error")
    })
}
```

Comment: Hola @Pizza, para que te puedan ayudar debes proporcionar más información, coloca el código de lo que has intentado. Realiza el recorrido para que veas como preguntar. https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de la librería [universal-cookie](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/universal-cookie).

```
npm i universal-cookie
```

```js
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

const cookies = new Cookies();

cookies.set('myCat', 'Pacman', { path: '/' });
console.log(cookies.get('myCat')); // Pacman
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es mio usalo me funciona esta en typescript:

```
const Cookie = {
        
   set:(key:string, value:string, exdays:number) => {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    let v = encodeURIComponent(value)
    document.cookie = key + "=" + v + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
  },

  get:(key:string):string =>{
    var name = key + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);

    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return "";
  },
  delete: (key:string)=>{
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (-10*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = key + "=" + "" + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
  }
}


export default Cookie
```